# Measure a 5cm Cube's displacement with sub-micron accuracy within a small position uncertainty 20cm away

Tags: optics, lasers, metrology

The 5cm cube in the question is a place holder in terms of geometry for what we want to track and measure its displacement.

The problem is quite simplified with that we know already the cube is put in front of the measurement device **always only 20cm away (from a known side of it)**. And, the cube would be displaced only within a **5cm and 25 degrees uncertainty**.

The measurement device on the other side should fit in a 10cm, for example, and can't be bigger. It is allowed to put any active or passive elements on the target cube.

The question is how to measure the displacement of its pose within sub-micron accuracy. There is no need for high frequency measurements but rather accurate ones.

Possible idea: put a few LEDs on the cube with a small aperture in front of them. and for the measurement device side, have a camera chip, similar to those of mobile phones, and have a lense or slit or diffraction grating in front of it. It is also possible to use more cameras as long as we don't exceed the size of the measurement cube.

My question is how would you approach these requirements and if the idea I have could work, or if so, what design may be good in terms of Lens, aperturate of if neeeded, prism/diffractive-elements...

Comment: Trying to detect angular motion from a single camera is tricky, as is motion along the focal axis. So, 4000 pixels, .001 mm resolution (not accuracy), your 50mm cube at 200mm away moves to 200.001 mm away, your leds are now 50/200.001 apart rather than 50/200. it's your project, you do the maths. Gut feeling nope.

Comment: Quick calc if you've got 4000 pixels with 50mm field of view at 200 mm, at 200 the leds are 4000 pixels apart, at 200.001 they are 4000.02 pixels apart. So your resolution in X is more like 50 microns.

Comment: @GregLocock but are you taking into account the magnification of the lense? something is needed probably to increase the image displacement on the chip with a proportional gain compared to the displacement of the LED

Comment: note that I can use more than one camera as long as all cameras don't make a setup bigger than a 10cm cube. and the Cameras angel don't have to be all parallel

Comment: if the field of view is 50 mm and you have 4000 pixels then the most resolution is going to be 50/4000, whatever the magnification, which is a lot more than 1 micron

Comment: Another issue is that 1 micron is 2 wavelengths of blue light. How is your led going to be that small?

Comment: @GregLocock there is also the possibility to use multiple cameras though. The LEDs can also be behind a small aperture, no?

Comment: I don't know, it may be possible, but not by using my schoolboy knowledge of optics.